# What are the "suggested edit stats" mentioned in the 10k tools page?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits, 10k-tools

The [access to moderator tools page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) mentions that you can view the "suggested edit stats":

> You now have access to various lists and statistical reports, giving you a broad overview of activity on the site:
>
> Posts with extreme votes
>
> Posts with the most comments/views/edits
>
> Recently protected questions
>
> Recently closed/reopened questions
>
> Recently migrated questions
>
> Recently deleted/undeleted posts
>
> Questions with pending close/reopen votes
>
> Posts with pending delete/undelete votes
>
> New answers to old questions
>
> **Suggested edit stats**
>
> The full history of reviews by all users in any /review queue

(Emphasis mine.) What are the suggested edit stats?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Suggested edit stats has the list of all the approved/rejected/pending suggested edits of the period of day/week/month/all.

Also with the filter of it's type, like the following:

> all : All suggested edits
>   approved: Approved suggested edits
>   rejected: Rejected suggested edits
>   controversial: Edits with both approved and reject votes
>   anonymous: Edits submitted anonymously
>   improved: Edits that were approved using the improve function

<sub>Note: The description of the filter type taken from the tooltip when hover the options</sub>

The screenshot of the suggested edit stats is:

> [image: suggested edit stats]