# Display suggested edits where the post owner overruled all reviewers under the 'Controversial' or a separate tab on the dashboard

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, 10k-tools

If a suggested edit is rejected by all reviewers, [the post owner is still able to view this suggestion and still decide to apply the edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295028/). If so, the edit is considered "approved" and made under the name of the user who suggested the edit.

Sometimes, the post owner makes a mistake and overrides and approves a rejected edit that is clearly detrimental (e.g. a spam link), and either does not realize this mistake or otherwise forgets to do something about it. It could also be useful to see whether a certain type of edit is often rejected by reviewers but accepted by owners, and improve reviewing guidelines.

As far as I'm aware, there currently is no easy way to find the suggestions where the post owner overrides all reviewers. (It may be possible in SEDE, but I'm unfamiliar with that tool.) They are listed in the Approved tab (`/tools/suggested-edits?tab=approved`), in the same heap as all other approved reviews, so this is not very helpful.

Edit suggestions that one reviewer has rejected and other *reviewers* have approved are listed under the "Controversial" tab `/tools/suggested-edits?tab=controversial`. Please also list edits whose outcome was overridden by the author under the "Controversial" tab, or list them under a separate tab, so these suggestions can be more easily found.

---

This feature request is related to, but not quite the same as not having such reviews to be considered as "approved" for the sake of the dashboard. (The latter is related to the behavior described [in this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248542/suggested-edits-dashboard-in-10-k-tools-list-users-who-rejected-an-edit-as-appro), which I can confirm still is the case.) I don't really care how these suggestions are called, I just want to find them.

Comment: DL, is your question related to: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323285/282094 --- I suggest that the OP's approval or rejection is **not** deemed by Stack Exchange as "controversial"; for example [I can reject the moderator's decision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAATW.jpg) - where it's "controversial" is where there is a Rollback War, that alerts the moderators. --- A new tab is OK, but it might require a different name.

Comment: Suggestion: [Vetos](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/veto) tab - Where everything was cut and dried but one person (not a mod or CM) overrode or reversed the decision - to include 'dupe flag' overridden by 'Gold Tag Hammer', etc.

Comment: @Rob I haven't seen those tool-tips yet, thanks. However, even though these edits are not considered 'controversial' at the present, it is still an option to expand the scope of 'controversial' and put them in the same tab. One argument against putting it in the same tab could be that the 'controversial' tab (or the 'overridden' suggestions) may be a large heap on some sites (it is not on [cs.se], I don't know about other sites).

Comment: As for new tab names, I think 'Overridden' is also a good option, as the action is referred to this way in other places.